# Delete text from a bunch of .obj files at once using terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

How can I delete the text `ATTR_shiny_rat 0.900` from a bunch of `.obj` files at once using terminal?

Comment: What are `.obj` files and how do they look like? Could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

```sh
for i in *.obj; do
  grep -v 'ATTR_shiny_rat\s0\.900' "$i" > temp
  rm "$i"
  mv temp "$i"
done
```

Comment: What happens if there's already a file `temp` in the current working directory? It would be lost in the process.